# C# write bytes to stdout adds random bytes to the output

Tags: c#, character-encoding, stdout, chrome-native-messaging

I have the following code in a .NET 6 project:

```
using var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
stdout.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint) 8));
stdout.Flush();
```

I am running from PowerShell like this `./program.exe > ./output`. I expected the output to be a file containing 4 bytes with the following hex values: `08 00 00 00`. However, the output actually contains 14 bytes: `FF FE 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0D 00 0A 00`.

I understand the first 2 bytes is the BOM for UTF16LE ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)).
The last 4 bytes are `\r\n` (CRLF).
And the middle bytes are what I am writing, I believe encoded for UTF16LE.

I don't understand why all this extra information is added. If I go as far as writing straight to stdout why doesn't the framework assume I did all the necessary encoding and I am writing exactly the bytes I want to write. Why does it have to add all this extra information and how can I stop it from doing this? I am banging my head on the wall.

## Context

I cannot allow any extra bytes to be written because I am working with [Chrome Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) which expects the first 4 bytes to be the length of the message followed by the message itself. It uses stdout/stdin to read/write between the host app (C# app in my case) and the extension. If I could write to another stream I would in a heartbeat, but I cannot.

Comment: You've apparently validated that the BOM is for UTF16LE, UTF16 means each character takes 2 bytes, your "extra" bytes after accounting for the BOM and new lines, is exactly 4 bytes, which is what you would expect if the text is encoded using UTF16.  So is your question just "why is this being output as UTF-16 instead of UTF-8?"

Comment: I don't want any encoding, I am passing an array of bytes and I want exactly that to be written to stdout.

Edit: I also don't want CRLF to be added as that's not part of the original byte array.

Comment: @GeorgeD, you do want encoding. According to the link, Chrome Native Messaging expects UTF-8. I am not sure where the BOM bytes or the CRLF bytes are coming from, but I think it is on the powershell side (or maybe a text editor is adding it?), i.e. when you open/close a file via powershell these bytes are automatically included. According to the documentation, `Console.Write` does not insert CRLF or a BOM. By the way, I would make a `BinaryWriter`: `var binaryWriter = new(stdout, Encoding.UTF8);` to do the writing. This ensures utf-8 encoding for your api.

Comment: @dmedine Thank you, you are right about the encoding. However I am unsure if this applies to the first 4 bytes as well which are used to determine the size of the mesaage. I will try running the code from another shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything happened because of PowerShell. The code works as expected and outputs the correct bytes, but PowerShell was taking those bytes and encoded them to UTF16LE.

Running `Program.exe > output` produces the expected result when run in `cmd.exe`.

Thank you a thousand times @dmedine, I was banging my head against the wall but I was just testing in the wrong environment.

Comment: Thanks for circling back with your solution.  Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: I will when StackOverflow allows me to.